# I need to create a report in HTML, that is A4 size, how can i do that?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a report in HTML that is supposed to be A4 size exactly.  It needs headers and footers.  Surely this can be done with css yeah?

does anyone have any examples or sample code for this?

I googled and the code snippets I got all talk about media queries and they don't work..

so basically it is for print Purposes, the html generated will be converted to a PDF document.
I am using MVC4 and found a tool that will convert a view to a PDF.  A view is just pure HTML.  So I thought why not style the HTML to represent the output report, then PDF it.

So I need the ability to have a header, and a footer (bottom of the page) and then content in the middle of both of them

I tried using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work..

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @page {
            size: A4 portrait; /* can use also 'landscape' for orientation */
            margin: 1.0in;
            border: thin solid black;
            padding: 1em;

            @bottom-center {
                content: element(footer);
            }

            @top-center {
                content: element(header);
            }
        }

        #page-header {
            display: block;
            position: running(header);
        }

        #page-footer {
            display: block;
            position: running(footer);
        }

        .page-number:before {
            content: counter(page); 
        }

        .page-count:before {
            content: counter(pages);  
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-header">
        <p>Header text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="page-footer">
        <p>Footer text</p>
        <p>Page <span class="page-number"/> of <span class="page-count"/></p>
    </div>

    <div id="page-content">
        <p>Page 1.</p>

        <p style="page-break-after:always;"/>

        <p>Page 2.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I honestly think media queries are the way to go.   Isn't that exactly what they are designed for?   `@media print` lets you define exactly how the page should look when printed.   But...  I've never tried something like this, so it's just a 'first thought' kind of thing...

Comment: any examples? i tried using http://www.fanuriotimetracking.com/files/releases/2.7/help/html/template-guide-html.html   go to the sample page.. doesnt work

Comment: `#a4 { width: 8.27in; height: 11.69in; }`

Answer (score 2):

CSS can be used to set width/height to a real-world size; for example in your print.css file:

```
div.A4 {
  width: 21 cm;
  height: 29.7 cm;
  margin: 0;
}
```

However, HTML/CSS really isn't meant for this purpose; media queries really are the best way to handle this. I'd really recommend you put a little more time trying to get them working; it's worth the time if you plan on using this website more than once.

Comment: @user2206329 if you need this for printing I strongly recommend not to hard-code the paper format dimensions using css because the user can change the paper format or even the orientation (landscape, portrait) use media queries instead

Comment: Very much agreed, but since OP specifically didn't want media queries, I thought I'd offer another way to do it. But yes, media queries are far, far preferable.

Comment: i never said I didn't want media queries.. I said the media queries I used didn't work.  If someone has some media queries that work.. more than happy to use them

Comment: @user2206329: in that case, let's try to get those media queries working! Can you explain what exactly isn't working about them?

Answer (score 1):

Why A4 size? For printing purposes? 
If for printing purposes you wont even have to worry about it. Use CSS for that purpose.
If your html element is displaying as a block element (the default) and you don't specify any width or height then the html document will resize to the printer settings document when you attempt to print.
If you ever need to adjust any css settings for printing then use [css media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)

Ignore this answer if it's not related to printing, but provide more details in your post so we can provide the correct solution.

Hope it makes sense

Leo

Comment: Is this PDF converter tool capable of handling printing and paper formats? What tool is it? I have used other PDF converters  for MVC and ASP.NEt and they usually handle this stuff in a nice OO fashion

Comment: As I suspected, you can set all that stuff (orientation, size, margins, etc) at the PDF tool level itself. Check out the following object, it extends an ActionResult object...https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/blob/master/Rotativa/AsPdfResultBase.cs

Comment: It contains all the options you're looking for